# Use Minidom to parse XML But just crashes applet

Tags: python, xml

Having some issues with Minidom for parsing an XML file on a remote server.

This is the code I am trying to parse:

```
<mod n="1">
<body>
Random Body information will be here
</body>
<b>1997-01-27</b>
<d>1460321480</d>
<l>United Kingdom</l>
<s>M</s>
<t>About Denisstoff</t>
</mod>
```

I'm trying to return the `<d>` values with Minidom. This is the code I am trying to use to find the value:

```
expired = True
f = urlreq.urlopen("http://st.chatango.com/profileimg/"+args[:1]+"/"+args[1:2]+"/"+args+"/mod1.xml")
data = f.read().decode("utf-8")
      dom = minidom.parseString(data)
      itemlist = dom.getElementsByTagName('d')
      print(itemlist)
```

It returns the value is there, but I followed a way to read the data I found here (Below) and it just crashed my python app. This is the code I tried to fix with:

```
for s in itemlist:
          if s.hasAttribute('d'):
              print(s.attributes['d'].value)
```

This is the crash:

```
AttributeError: 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I also tried ElementTree but that didn't return any data at all. I have tested the URL and it's correct for the data I want, but I just can't get it to read the data in the tags. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: this code cannot produce this error. `itemlist` is of type `NodeList` but `s.attributes['d']` is of type `Attr` and as an attribute `value`.

Comment: Hi, Daniel. Here is a screenshot so you can see it produces this very error.

https://gyazo.com/0e63513480e980248615fc63c6361de2

Comment: @MichaelWallace you're doing `itemlist.value` there, instead of `s.attributes['d'].value` as posted in this question

Comment: It was an exact copy from my code to the post, and I didn't change anything inside the code after posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to print values from this xml you should use this:

```
for s in itemlist:
    if hasattr(s.childNodes[0], "data"):
        print(s.childNodes[0].data)
```

I hope it help :D

Comment: That did it. Now it actually displays the data like I need it to. Thanks very much :)